NETs or something else? (Found while filtering circulating tumor cells from patient`s blood)

I filter circulating tumor cells from blood of patients with metastatic breast cancer (С50) and I`ve found this on several filters. And I have these "clouds" on them. Can it be something other than NETs (Neutrophil Extracellular Traps)?

What kind of Breast Ca, specifically?

C50 Malignant neoplasm of breast

No idea, then. You'll need to consult your pathologist for this question.
